# Firebase Android - Check if value is already exists

Tags: android, firebase

I need help regarding checking if the value is already exists in the database so Users won't be able to change it to the same number when they're updating it, like a unique ID

I've been searching for hours for a solution but I can't find any that's working.

[image: ID]

Comment: For example if the current ID is 102, they won't be able to change it to 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended before you should have a data structure, an index list, for this, why? Because when you have tons of this *ids* it will be a better query. However, I think what you are trying to do is complementary to the previous suggestions.

What you have to do is use a single event listener, if the datasnapshot is not null, then the value exists. The key is query the id you need:

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference();
DatabaseReference reference = root.child("Test").oderByChild("ID").equalsTo(someId);

reference.addSingleValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       if (dataSnaphot != null) {
       //This means the value exist, you could also dataSnaphot.exist()
       }
    }
    //More auto generated code
);
```

The `dataSnapshot` is a bunch of your objects, because the query could match more than one result. You can iterate inside of it if you need the value of each:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           if (dataSnaphot != null) {
           for (DataSnapshot children : dataSnaphot.getChildrens()) {
               YourModel yourModel = children.getValue(YourModel.class);
           }
           }
        }
```

Comment: When the user click the keyboard button then get that text value and replace it, instead of `someId`, if the `dataSnaphot` is null then you can push the new value, otherwise handle the already exist value case @random1234

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, I recommend you create another node named `userIds`. Every time a new user is created just add the user id in this new section. This new section should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
    --- userIds
      --- Id101: true
      --- Id102: true
```

Then just put a listener on this new node node and use `exists()` method on the dataSnapshot object.

Comment: You are surely right about the data structure, but why not make a database rule for the exist method?

Comment: This is the simplest approach.

Comment: Will the ID be connected to the User?

Comment: @J.Doe how do I do that? I study up the database rules last night but it got me really confused :|

Comment: In this case, just follow the indications above and your problem will be solved ;)

Comment: ah! I just understand you, that's inside the database rule. My bad.

Comment: is the Id101 and Id102 refers to the value itself or the child? Can you explain to me? it's a bit confusing on my end.

Comment: Yes, it is like that.